# Using pretrained feature-extractor in pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm new to scikit-learn, and can't find the answer to what I think is a common use-case. I have lots of unlabelled data, and only some labelled data. I want to first train a transformer for feature-extraction, then save that part of the pipeline somewhere. Then, I'd like to create a pipeline of the feature-extractor plus a classifier, which I'll train on labelled data.

But, I don't want the feature-extractor to re-fit on the new data -- I want it to keep its parameters from when I trained it on the unlabelled data.

Can somebody point me in the direction of how best to do this? Thank you.